# Sorting with quadratic method of Objects but "compareTo" error occurs at Comparsion in if statement

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

```
public static void quadraticSort(Message[] m)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i +=1)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j += 1)
        {
          int k = m[i].compareTo(m[j]);
          if (k < 0)
          {
            swap(s, i, j);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Message class

```
enum Subject {PERSONAL, FAMILY, WORK, GENERAL}
//Q4 Task 5
public class Message
{

    String    messageText;
    User from;
    User to;
    Subject subject;
    public Message(Subject subject, User from, User to, String messageText)
    {
        this.subject        = subject;
        this.from           = from;
        this.to             = to;
        this.messageText    = messageText;
    } 

    public void displayMessage()
    {
        String nameFrom = from.firstName;
        String nameTo   = to.firstName;
        System.out.println("Message subject: " + subject+ " "+ nameFrom + " says \""+messageText + "\" to " + nameTo);
    }

    public void displayMessageContent()
    {
        System.out.println(messageText);
    }
}
```

My question is in regards to the compareTO  i can't seem to get it to work. it keeps popping up cannot find symbol compareTO(Message)

I'm a total noob at this so any help would be very appreciated.
My regards for for time.

This is the homework question , perhaps it'll clear this area up

Write a method in MessageSort to sort an array of messages.

- Signature: public static void sortMessages(Message[] messages)
- Use the sorting algorithm developed in this assignment to sort the list
- Test your code by invoking sortArrayMessages on an instance of TestMessaging class provided (Figure 6)

Comment: Please show your `Message` class's `compareTo` implementation and the *exact* error message.

Comment: Your question title says you are comparing strings, but your code is comparing Message objects. Maybe you meant to pick out one member of the Message? Or maybe you meant to implement compareTo on the Message as a whole?

Comment: does Message extend Comparable?

Comment: Yes i think you are right - comparing Message objects, forgive me for my inaccuracy. I'm still trying to get my head around this language

Comment: No compareTo it doesn't extend to Message class. I thought it was built into java util Arraylist

Comment: regardless of whether an ArrayList itself is comparable or not, you are still comparing the elements INSIDE an ArrayList, so it is that element that needs to be Comparable. Again, post the implementation of `Message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a compareTo method

change your class to:

```
public class Message implements Comparable { 
....
```

then implement the compareTo() method in your class.

Comment: We are limited to the amount of methods we can create . I can't create a new method in the Message class. I may go back to the drawing board and think this one out. Thanks for your help Ben. I fear this is above my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void quadraticSort(Message[] m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i += 1)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < m.length; j += 1)
        {
            String a = m[i].messageText;
            String b = m[j].messageText;
            int k = b.compareTo(a);
            if( k < 0)
            {
                swap(m, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void swap(Message[] arMsg, int to, int from)
{
    Message temp = arMsg[to];
    arMsg[to] = arMsg[from];
    arMsg[from] = temp;
}
```

Only the messageText part is a String, this code will fix it that your compareTo will only take the messageText into account. I've included my swap in case you want a look.